Setting Up LDAP Authentication for Teradata ODBC Connection in R Without Manual Credential Input
I performed the necessary configuration in the ODBC driver version 16.20 DSN Setup, and the connection seems to work. However, in R, I want to establish the connection without having to manually enter my credentials. In theory, this should be possible with LDAP authentication. Despite configuring all the necessary credentials in the ODBC.INI file, the connection is still failing. Does anyone know what might be causing the issue? Could someone explain the correct way to set up authentication in Teradata so that the ODBC connection does not ask for credentials in R?
I tested the connection using the connection test tool in the ODBC driver, and it worked fine. Additionally, I manually edited the ODBC.INI file to include the necessary credentials, but none of these steps solved the issue. I am aware that an alternate solution involves using rstudioapi, but I would prefer not to manually enter my credentials. My goal is to establish the connection without having to input credentials each time.

Consider using Teradata SQL Driver for R rather than (an old version of) Teradata ODBC and RODBC layer. But in general, LDAP authentication does not support "single sign-on". Kerberos and OIDC/SAML based authentication methods can potentially be used for that, but adding authentication methods requires configuration on the database end as well.
